# wp7 incremental purchases

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

In my WP7 app, I want to provide the basic functionality as free (level 1).  Then, to get the next level (2) the user needs to buy.  I am familiar with the IsTrial() method and I can use that for this purpose.

What happens though if I want to sell the next level (level 3 and later level 4) of the app to this user who has already purchased level 2 or level 3? How do I do that?

Pratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have "Purchased" or "Trial" There is no in between. If you need multiple levels, you may have to submit your app multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt response.

Answer (score 3):

There is only paid and not paid supported by the platform. In app purchases, etc, are not available at the moment.